# Using variables with .insertAfter is not working

Tags: jquery, css, html, variables, insertafter

I'm a beginner coder and my English is very bad, so i apologize in front. I have the following CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid 1px #000; 
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.page{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}
#page1{
    background-color: #CF9; 
}
#page2{
    background-color: #FC9;
}
#page3{
    background-color: #99F;
}
h1{
    color: white;   
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="page" id="page1"><h1>page1</h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="#page1">page 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#page2">page 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#page3">page 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="page" id="page2"><h1>page1</h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="#page1">page 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#page2">page 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#page3">page 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="page" id="page3"><h1>page1</h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="#page1">page 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#page2">page 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#page3">page 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

And the Jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".page a").click(function(){
        fromURL=$(this).closest(".page").attr("id");
        toURL = $(this).attr("href");
        $(toURL).insertAfter(fromURL);
        //$("#page3").insertAfter("#page1"); //this works
        })


    });
```

It seems that the .insertAfter does not work with vars. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

`fromURL` is an ID without a hash symbol, so it looks like an element name to jQuery, so it doesn’t select anything. You could make it an ID selector:

```
$(toURL).insertAfter("#" + fromURL);
```

but you have the element anyways. Who needs IDs?

```
var page = $(this).closest(".page");
var toURL = $(this).attr("href");
$(toURL).insertAfter(page);
```

Declare your variables, by the way. Implicit globals are bad. Strict mode and JSHint can help with this.

Comment: Thank you very much minitech! This solves my problem! Also thank you for your tip.

Comment: @user3407921 then accept the answer by clicking the 'accept' button